# AutoMapper and Navigational Properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller, automapper, viewmodel

Has anyone every come across the following situation. I have an MVC app and I am using Entity Framework. I have a foreign key that I am populating into a drop down box and when the user selects their choice and submits the form I get an error about not being able to map.

I have the following Entites:

```
public Class City{
 public int Id {get; set;}
 public string Name {get; set;}
}


public class Property {
 public int Id {get; set;}
 public string Description {get; set;}
 public Virtual City City {get; set;}
}
```

I have the following View Model

```
public class AddPropertyVM {

  public AddPropertyViewModel(IEnumerable<City> cities){
    _cities = cities;
  } 

  public AddPropertyViewModel(){}

  public string Description {get; set;}
  public int SelectedCityId {get; set;}
  public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CitiesItems {
    get {
      return new SelectList(_cities, "Id", "Name");
    }
  }

  private IEnuermable<City> _cities {get; set;}
}
```

I have the following AutoMapper Configuration:

```
config.CreateMap<Property, AddPropertyViewModel>().ReverseMap();
```

When I try to map the VM back to the property entity like this:

```
var newProperty = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<AddPropertyViewModel, Property>(property);
```

I get the following error:

Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

Mapping types:
Int32 -> City
System.Int32 -> Test.Entities.City

Destination path:
Property.City.City

Source value:
2

Does anyone know why this is happening? Any help / guidance would be very much appreciated.

Just so it's clear. I am trying to get City back from SelectedCityId.

I've tried setting up AfterMap but I'm still having the same issue:

```
config.CreateMap<AddPropertyViewModel, Property>().AfterMap((s, d) => d.City = new City { id = s.City });
```

Comment: Not trying to be rude, but if I see you map a `Property` to an `AddPropertyViewModel` I wonder if you understand what AutoMapper is for. The only property that can be mapped by convention is `Description`. For the rest I don't see any specified member mappings. Also, I think you have a typo or two. The class name should be `AddPropertyViewModel`, and AutoMapper can't possibly pair `SelectedCityId` and `City` (which it apparently does).

Comment: Hi thanks. I actually have more properties on the Entity and VM that match up. I only listed a few properties here for brevity. I tried changing SelectedCityId to City however that doesn't work either. I'm not sure how to map to an Navigational property. I have the City id but automapper can't map that to a City object.

Comment: No, of course it can't. How do you imagine it should do that by itself?

Comment: The Automapper needs some extra configuration. That's why I'm asking if anyone has had a similar situation. I'm playing with AfterMap at the moment. I might be able to create a new City

Comment: @GertArnold Updated as suggested

Comment: Well, there is no `s.City`. You lost me.

Comment: When playing about with the mapping. I tried changing s.SelectedCityId to s.City . They are both the same value.

Comment: But you could get list of all cities, and pass it to ViewModel - you don't need DTO for that, and mapping classes..

Answer (score 0):

your property class has single object City but the other class has ienumerable ...

```
private IEnuermable<City> _cities {get; set;}
```

You should make both classes compatible to each other.

Comment: Yes - The property has only one City. However the VM creates a drop down of all cities on in the DB so I grab all cities and pass it to VM constructor and build the select list. I can't really see any other way of doing it

Comment: Automapper creates mapping based on same member names. In you case you would have to make custom mapping something like this: config.CreateMap<Property, AddPropertyViewModel>().ForMember(
                                                                dest => dest.SelectedCityId,
                                                                opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id)
                                                            )

Comment: If you need a lookup list to pick cities from you could use map.UseValues. Declare a list in your VM for example like this :

public string[] Sharetypes { get; set; }

and then map it with something like this: 

.ForMember(vm => vm.Sharetypes, map =>                   map.UseValue(Enum.GetNames(typeof(ShareType)).ToArray()));

In the example I am getting a list of enum names, but you should be able to change it to a query to return a list of city objects